# Is it possible to query multiple Longitude and Latitude loctions from Google APIs with multiple zip codes?

Tags: google-api, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Basically I've a use-case that I need to fetch multiple longitude and latitudes on multiple zip codes. So that I can avoid multiple requests to the Google servers and can reduce costs as well as make my code more efficient.

**Request for single request look like below:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10001&sensor=false&key=<some_key>
```

*And this works fine for the single request. But I want to know if there is some method using which multiple geolocation data can be fetched?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch process with google geocoding api webservices (looking for updates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349251/batch-process-with-google-geocoding-api-webservices-looking-for-updates)

Comment: Thanks, it can be partially used, but ideally I'm looking for something to query these locations in bulk. In answers of the link you are shared one person talks about using Directions API instead, which I've to explore, but it can be an option if it does the job.